# having trouble with audio fallback

Tags: html

I'm trying to use the HTML5 audio tag in Firefox or other browsers other than Google Chrome, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
The control displays in Firefox, but it doesn't seem to play the file.

Here's my code:

```
 <audio id="audioplayer" preload controls loop style="width:424px;">
 <source src="02-24-13 Ed Randall with Art Shamsky.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 Your browser does not support the audio element.
 </audio>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var audioTag = document.createElement('audio');
 if (!(!!(audioTag.canPlayType) && ("no" != audioTag.canPlayType("audio/mpeg")) && ("" != audioTag.canPlayType("audio/mpeg")))) {
 AudioPlayer.embed("audioplayer", {soundFile: "02-24-13 Ed Randall with Art Shamsky.mp3"});
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean? What errors to you get? Also, I'd recommend not using spaces in file names.

Comment: Add more info to the question, that will help people to undertand your problem, and so, the solution can be more specific.

Comment: The MP3 seems to play fine in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer, but not in Firefox. What should I do to get it to work in Firefox?

Comment: Is there a way to do browser detection and play ogg instead of mp3 for Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Acoording to MDN mp3 format is not supported in Firefox browser. take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats)